# How to get image from MultipleChoiceItem in Google Form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Form with multiple choice questions, with each choice having an image associated with it. For a task unrelated to this issue, I need to write a script that captures the image attached to the respondent's choice.

I've tried manipulating the ItemResponse and MultipleChoiceItem instances but can't seem to find a way to access the image.

```
function getChoiceImage (e) {
  return e.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse()
}
```

I expected this to contain (among other stuff) the image instance (ImageItem), which I could then apply other methods to. Instead, all I get back is the choice's text description.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried poking around e.response.getItemResponses()? or even e? Sometimes the layout is not what you would expect. It is also possible the attached image isn't part of the response itself, in which case you would have to construct the mapping yourself

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm new to working with Google Apps script so I could be wrong, but all getItemResponses() returns is an array of items, each item being a ItemResponse instance and I don't think I'm able to work with these in any way other than the methods they give you.

By construct the mapping myself, do you mean query the form page for the image element?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is an [open ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765518) at Google.

To get around this, I wrote a function that compares the value of the respondents choice to the array of choices in that multiple choice question, and returns what index it was found at. This relies on having the images on file, having them in the order they appear in the form (specify array target by index returned), and having the index of the MC Item within the form.

```
function getChoiceIndex (e, itemIndex) { 
  var choice = e.response.getItemResponses()[itemIndex].getResponse(), index;
  var choices = e.response.getItemResponses()[itemIndex].getItem().asMultipleChoiceItem().getChoices()
  // get index of selected choice in arr of choices  
  for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    if (choices[i].getValue() === choice) {
      index = i
    }
  }
  return index
}
```